# Thymeleaf - How to pass variables in internal CSS?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am sending user object from spring boot controller and I want to pass user.result in width property. How to do it in Thymeleaf?

```
<style>
        @keyframes width {
            0% {
                width: 0%;
            }

            100% {
                  width: 10%;    // like this width: ${user.result}%;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: The linked duplicate answer uses `<style th:inline="text">`. But you can also use `<style th:inline="css">` - see [CSS Inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#css-inlining) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't supporting now in pure native css, but there are in css preprocessors.

Comment: You can use Thymeleaf's `<style th:inline="text">`, as shown in the linked duplicate answer, and also `<style th:inline="css">`.

Comment: Variables actually are supported in pure native css.  You just need to configure controllers for your CSS files (just like you do for your HTML files -- making sure to set your resolvers template mode to CSS like this `resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.CSS);`).